# Creating a list where a certain char occur a set number of times

Tags: python, arrays, list, python-2.7

I am creating a list in python 2.7
The list consists of 1's and 0's however I need the 1's to appear randomly in the list and a set amount of times.

Here is a way I found of doing this however can take a long time to create the list

```
numcor = 0




while numcor != (wordlen):    #wordlen being the set amount of times
    usewrong = []

    for l in list(mymap):

        if l == "L": #L is my map an telling how long the list needs to be
            use = random.choice((True, False))
            if use == True:
                usewrong.append(0)
            else:
                usewrong.append(1)
                numcor = numcor + 1
```

Is there a more effiecient way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Simpler to way to create the list with `0`s and '1's is:

```
>>> n, m = 5, 10
>>> [0]*n + [1]*m
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

where `n` is the number of `0`s and `m` is the number of `1`s

However if you want *the list to be shuffled in random order*, you may use [`random.shuffle()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle) as:

```
>>> from random import shuffle
>>> mylist = [0]*n + [1]*m  # n and m are from above example
>>> shuffle(mylist)
>>> mylist
[1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]
```

Comment: You need to shuffle it then as the requirement is a randomly arranged list

Comment: Updated the answer with shuffling as well

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different approach:

```
from random import *
# create a list full of 0's
ls = [0 for _ in range(10)]
# pick e.g. 3 non-duplicate random indexes in range(len(ls))
random_indexes = sample(range(len(ls)), 3)
# create in-place our random list which contains 3 1's in random indexes
ls = [1 if (i in random_indexes) else ls[i] for i,j in enumerate(ls)]
```

The output will be:

```
>>> ls
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

Comment: "1's to appear randomly in the list and a **set amount of times**"